# ModelMapper после преобразования вложенный обьект равен Null

Tags: java, mapper

Для уменьшения кода конструкторы, геттеры и сеттеры приводить не буду
Чтобы не приводить все поля классов, я их упростил, поэтому сущность = dto.

Java 17 version

У меня есть две сущности

```
class Order {
  String name;
  Address address;
}

class Address {
  String street;
  String city;
}
```

И dto

```
class OrderDto {
  String name;
  AddressDto address;
}

class AddressDto {
  String street;
  String city;
}
```

Мне надо преобразовать объект Order в OrderDTO, и чтобы при этом свойство Address исходного объекта тоже было отображено в новом.
Для преобразования использую ModelMapper:

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
OrderDTO orderDTO = modelMapper.map(order, OrderDTO.class);
```

и в результате получаю свойство Address равно Null

```
orderDto.getAddressDto == Null
```

Можно это как это реализовать с помощью ModelMapper?

Пробовал Такой вариант

```
TypeMap<User, UserDto> rateDTORateTypeMap = mapper.getTypeMap(Address.class, AddressDto.class);
if(rateDTORateTypeMap == null) {
    rateDTORateTypeMap = mapper.createTypeMap(Address.class, AddressDto.class);
}
OrderDTO orderDTO = modelMapper.map(order, OrderDTO.class);
```

результат тот же

Comment: Вы уверены, что у вас в исходном объекте `order.Address != null`?

Comment: @Pak Uula, Да, он у меня в логах отображается